# Visualg - Atribuir à duas variáveis na mesma linha

Tags: visualg, portugol

Gostaria de saber como coloco 1 variável ao lado da outra no visualg?

```
Exemplo:

1.0  7.0
5.0  9.0
```

Sendo que os 4 números são variáveis REAIS, para simplificar quero escrever 1.0 em baixo 5.0 ai o cursor sobe escrevo 7.0 e em baixo 9.0

```
var

   X1, X2, Y1, Y2, R:REAL


inicio

      Leia(X1)
      Leia(X2)
      Leia(Y1)
      Leia(Y2)
      R <- raizq((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1))//FORM CALCULAR DISTANCIA
      Escreval (R:1:4)



fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: O exemplo acima não ficou como gostaria mais o exercício é esse https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1015

Comment: Coloque dois ESCREVAL, um embaixo do outro, na linha de cima coloque ESCREVAL( e as respectivas variaveis  de 1.0 e 7.0) no ESCREVAL de baixo ( as respectivas variáveis de 5.0 e 9.0)  tentou fazer isso já? Poste seu código que te ajudamos!

Comment: Vamos lá, se você abrir o link ali da atividade vai ver que onde está input sample(onde o usuario coloca os valores) está alinhado um ao lado do outro. Quero saber o comando para deixar meu código dessa forma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consoante o manual da Linguagem Portugol, a função leia permite a entrada de dados, recebendo os  valores digitados pelos usuário, atribuindo-os à variável declarada juntamente com o a função leia.

> **3.5.1 Funções internas**
>
> Como já foi visto em exemplos anteriores, G-Portugol oferece duas
>   funções internas: “leia” e “imprima”, que  permitem uso básico de
>   entrada e saída, respectivamente. A função “leia” não recebe
>   argumentos e retorna o valor lido da entrada padrão (“STDIN”), o que
>   significa, geralmente, *ler os dados que o usuário digitar no teclado,
>   seguido do caractere “nova linha” (em geral, associado a tecla “Enter”
>   no teclado)*. O tipo de dado retornado por “leia” é implicitamente
>   convertido para o tipo primitivo exigido no contexto em que ela é
>   usada.

Conforme a citação acima, subentende-se que o caractere 'nova linha' é que permite a atribuição do valor à respectiva variável.
 **Portanto não havendo a possibilidade de atribuir dois valores a duas variáveis diferentes NA MESMA LINHA, como vemos em outra linguagens - exemplo: python.**

Relembrando os objetivos da linguagem Portugol:

> "Por outro lado, submeter um iniciante aos rigores de uma linguagem de
>   programação como Pascal ou ao “esoterismo” do C também é exagerado. O
>   ideal seria **uma linguagem mais simples**, parecida com o "Portugol", de
>   grande popularidade nos meios acadêmicos e presente nos livros mais
>   utilizados; com ela, os princípios básicos da programação estruturada
>   podem ser ensinados sem que a curva de aprendizagem fosse íngreme."

Acredito que devido ao fato de  "Portugol" ter como objetivo ser uma linguagem simples para iniciantes não existe a possibilidade de [Atribuição múltipla como em Python](http://excript.com/python/atribuicao-multipla-python.html)

Fontes:

1. [Manual Portugol](https://inf.ufes.br/~mberger/Disciplinas/2015_2/Compiladores/manualGPortugol.pdf)
2. [Manual ferramenta Visualg](http://www.inf.ufsc.br/~bosco.sobral/ensino/ine5201/Visualg2_manual.pdf)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda colega! Acredito que meu professor tenha se equivocado ao passar essa atividade ou foi apenas um erro de interpretação de minha parte.

Comment: Verifique com ele, se você pode fazer em outra linguagem, que possuem diversos meios de fazer tal atribuição!

Answer (score 1):

Colocando escreva em vez de escreval, vai manter o proximo comando na mesma linha.

Ex.:

Var

A, B, C: inteiro

Inicio

A <- 2

B <- 3
C <- 5

Escreva ("A x B = ")

Escreval (A*B)

Escreval (C>A)

escreval (A>2)

Escreva (C=A+B)

Escreva (A+B)

Na tela preta:

A x B =  6
VERDADEIRO

FALSO

VERDADEIRO 5

> > > Fim da execução do programa !